# WSUS can't install/download updates

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, wsus

my WSUS server (Windows Server 2019) can't install/download updates to clients (Windows 10 Pro)
[Approve Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jWZi.png)

[Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxsXS.png)

I'm tried to reset BITS, clean temp files but the problem is still exist.

in WindowsUpdate log the error is:

*FAILED* [80246007] ISusInternal:: IsCommitRequired

I'm uploaded WindowsUpdate Log file:
https://secufiles.com/552bd35f1495c8d5/WindowsUpdateCens.rar

Please Help - Thanks!

Comment: Why are you installing 2021 updates in 2022? What is the build version of these installs?

Comment: It's happening with 2022 updates also.